# Обработка исключений PDO

Tags: php

Я сделал проверку для prepare, почему если указать неверную таблицу, то не выводит сообщение Подключение не удалось?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dz;charset=utf8";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
try{
    $statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `boks`');
}catch(PDOException $e){
     echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
     die();
}
```

Comment: потому что вы не выполняете запрос

Comment: prepare подготавливает запрос, если передать ошибочную таблицу, то вернёт false и должно сработать catch, но он почему-то не срабатывает

Comment: вы уж определитесь, либо вернет false, либо исключение. одновременно эти действия произойти не смогут.

Comment: в документации, кстати и написано "... или ...". Там же написано про режим эмуляции, в котором prepare не может проверить правильность запроса.